# select specific column only in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

my table-1 has 20 columns and table-2 has 15 columns. here i want to join two tables by user id .
i use this bellow query

```
SELECT  * FROM   table_checkout_bidpack as t1 inner JOIN table_user_information 
as t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
```

This query selects 35 columns but i need to select on columns(user_name) in the second table

i know this work

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4,.....,t2.user_name 
FROM   table_checkout_bidpack as t1 inner JOIN table_user_information 
as t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
```

This looks very big any other ways to do this

Comment: so you want all columns from t1 but only user_name from t2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select t1.*,t2.user_name 
FROM   table_checkout_bidpack as t1 inner JOIN table_user_information 
as t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*,t2.user_name 
FROM   table_checkout_bidpack as t1 inner JOIN table_user_information 
as t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
```

`*` is a wildcard selector, by itself it will match all columns in all tables, but if you prefix it with `table.` it will only match columns in that table.